# Memory management with python and VTK

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-management, vtk

I wrote a rather clunky python program that creates a unit cell of a certain geometry and duplicates it so that I get e.g. a 3x3x3 array of the unit cell. The result is saved as an .stl. The goal was to create these structures directly instead of using CAD.

My problem is that the computation time is annoying (~2 minutes for 8x8x8, which is smaller than what I need usually). The biggest problem is, that 10x10x10 isn't even possible. VTK immediately throws an error "Unable to allocate [large number] of elements of size 8 bytes." This leads me to believe that my memory management is insufficient (non-existent).

I read about `vtkSmartPointer`, but can only seem to find explanations for C++. How do I correctly use `vtkSmartPointer` with python? I should add that I do not have any experience with C++ whatsoever.

A MWE is kind of impossible due to the program size. Here's is a shortened example of a part of my algorithm pipeline instead:

```
import vtk

appendFilter = vtk.vtkAppendPolyData()

    # create all 12 struts and combine them into one object
    for i in range(1, 13, 1):
        tf = create_strut(i, node_dist, amp, d, sides, mode, render=False)  # method that creates my unit cell out of 12 struts, parameters are irrelevant
        appendFilter.AddInputData(tf.GetOutput())
        appendFilter.Update()

    # clean up poly data 
    cleanFilter = vtk.vtkCleanPolyData()
    cleanFilter.SetInputConnection(appendFilter.GetOutputPort())
    cleanFilter.Update()

    # cut the cell to its right size
    planes = plane_collection(node_dist)  # method that generates 6 planes
    clip = vtk.vtkClipClosedSurface()
    clip.SetInputData(cleanFilter.GetOutput())
    clip.SetClippingPlanes(planes)
    clip.Update()

    # assemble an array from the unit cell
    array = duplicate_cells(clip, xyz[0], xyz[1], xyz[2], node_dist)

    # save as .stl
    data = array.GetOutputPort()
    stlwriter = vtk.vtkSTLWriter()
    stlwriter.SetInputConnection(data)
    stlwriter.SetFileName("Z:/example.stl")
    stlwriter.Update()
    stlwriter.Write()
```

This should demonstrate that I use a lot of filters and never care about deleting them or anything. What is the correct/preferred way to clean up my memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I posted this I read a lot about VTK and Python came to the conclusion, that Python takes care of memory management itself. SmartPointers and Delete() should only be necessary in a C++ environment.

Furthermore I upgraded from Python 2.7 and VTK 6.2 to Python 3.4 and VTK 7.0 which vastly improved the overall performance of the program. Therefore, I think that the problem was with the old VTK version.